# How do i uninstall tasktop plugin from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tasktop

I have installed task top trial version long back.i want to uninstall it now how do i do that please let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try that in Eclipse:

```
Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details
```

Select the software and click on the button `Uninstall...`!

Comment: Much easier than what the [Tasktop docs said to do](https://tasktop.com/support/guide/#uninstallTasktopPlugins)!

Comment: If no variation of Tasktop Pro shows up in Installed Software, go to `Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installation History` and revert to a version before the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling the Tasktop plug-ins for Eclipse

Navigate to Help > About Eclipse 
Press "Installation Details" button 
Select the "Installed Software" tab 
Select "Tasktop Pro" from the list of installed software 
Press the "Uninstall..." button

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Help-->Install new Software

Click what install hyperlink

Find Tasktop and uninstall. Restart the eclipse.

This will remove Tasktop